# BorderStyle.Fixed3D renders flat on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8, controls

When I put a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` on a form in a WinForm application (using C#/.NET 4.5), it gets rendered as a flat rectangle, even though the `BorderStyle` property is set to `Fixed3D`. This is also true for `TextBox` and a number of other controls.

This is the code generated by the Form Designer for the `ListView`. The form is just a plain `Form` and has no other controls at the moment.

```
...
this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 115);
this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 97);
this.listView1.TabIndex = 2;
this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
...
```

If I open older programs (done with VB6 or .NET 2), control borders are rendered with 3D look (that is, controls are rendered with a proper 3D border) instead of being flat.

Is there anything I can do to force the 3D look for these controls under .NET 4.5?

Comment: try commenting out `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: @KingKing Thanks, that was it. I didn't look at that line at all. :)  Put in your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This surely works however I think it also **applies to all your controls** on your forms, just remove the line `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in the `Main()` method in `Program.cs` file.